# How to allow for return type

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider this code:

```
type deviceStatusType = string | boolean | number | undefined;

class A {
 protected constructor() {
        this.status = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "b"
        }
    }

    getDeviceStatus<T extends deviceStatusType>(arg: deviceStatusType,  code: string): T {
        const status = this.status[code];

        let actualType = typeof status;
        if (actualType !== arg){
            throw new Error(`mode should be a ${arg} but is: ${typeof(status)}`)
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
TS2322: Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'string | number | boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'deviceStatusType'.     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.       'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'deviceStatusType'.
```

on `return status` - but I really want to be able to move the typecheck into this function since that reduces the number of times I have to check the type to one place.

Comment: `typeof` always returns a `string` so your `arg` (i would name it allowedType or similar) suppose to be like `arg: 'string' | 'boolean' | 'number' | 'undefined'` (union of strings)

Comment: I'm not sure you need generic `T` at all. Please take a look here https://shorturl.at/ikopI Does this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already did the explicite type check, you could just declare `status` as `any` which you can assign to return value of `T`. If you want you can slightly improve it to

```
class A {
  getDeviceStatus<T extends deviceStatusType>(arg: T, code: string): T {
    const status = this.status[code];
    if (isType(status, arg)) {
        return status;
    }
    throw new Error(`mode should be a ${arg} but is: ${typeof(status)}`);
  }
}

function isType<T extends deviceStatusType>(actual: any, arg: T): actual is T {
  return typeof actual === arg;
}
```

Comment: Btw, you can use `assert` function instead of throwing error in `getDeviceStatus` directly

Comment: On platforms that have an `assert`, yes

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea!

In actual code this is actually a derived exception type